# Is it possible to create an Admin Password Key to conveniently login?

Tags: windows-7, passwords

I know a [USB password key](http://www.howtogeek.com/107657/build-a-usb-password-key-to-automatically-login-to-your-computer/) exists. However I was wondering was there a better way in logging into a Windows 7 computer as computer_name\administrator with a standard admin password?

For what purpose? 
Fast login as technical support who has to do several logins a day.

What Operating system? 
Windows 7

For what type of log-in (local or remote) With what level of security is still expected? 
Local login

Whos computer (yours or everyone elses)?
Everyone at the company

Comment: What version of Windows?  Windows support assigning a default user in which you can also store the password for that user.  There are many questions on Superuser that explains how to do that.  There are also several dozen tutorials that also exist.

Comment: And define 'better'

Answer (score 1):

Windows supports the use of **smart cards**, but it may or may not be "faster" than simply entering a regular password. It consists of inserting the smart card into the reader and entering a pin number:

> To log on to a Windows 7-based computer with a smart card:
>
> 1. Connect the smart card reader to your computer, if necessary.
> 2. Insert your smart card into the smart card reader.
> 3. Press Ctrl+Alt+Delete.
> 4. At the logon screen, click Switch User.
> 5. Click the smart card icon, type your PIN, and then press Enter.
>
> [Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/what-is-a-smart-card-and-how-do-i-use-one)

---

Windows 7 also introduced the [Biometric Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463081.aspx), which can work with fingerprint scanners to replace the regular password.

There are also third-party biometric solutions that replace the Windows password with a fingerprint or handprint scan. Some of them have the capability of identifying the user and logging them on in one step, speeding up the process.

---

I know your question applies to Windows 7, but in Windows 8 the "picture password" login method was introduced. It works similar to a pattern unlock in Android smartphones, in which a user draws a pattern instead of entering a password. There are several third-party alternatives that offer some form of pattern-based login.

Answer (score 1):

I just googled it and found a solution:

1. Download a free tool [VSUsbLogon](http://www.lokibit.com/download.htm#vsusblogon).
2. You'll need to put it on every
   machine.
3. Connect USB key and run the tool
4. Click Assign.   Enter your credentials and set method as auto logon.

That should do it.
You can find the full article [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/vsusblogon-log-in-windows-usb-drive)